# Installation of gcc for SimpleScalar on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu

So, I'm trying to install gcc for SimpleScalar-3.0, and I keep running into trouble when I execute the command `make install LANGUAGES="c c++" CFLAGS="-O3" CC="gcc"` as per the instructions in this wiki ([Link](http://wiki.bigbuddysociety.net/index.php?title=SimpleScalar_3.0#gcc))

I've included the entire output of the command as it runs in the first scroll box and the error message in the second scroll box. One source suggested that I re-install binutils, but that didn't seem to help remedy this problem. I also ensured that I have flex, and bison installed. I even tried removing flex and installing flex-old, but that didn't seem to help. Can anyone suggest a solution for my problem?

```
gcc -DCROSS_COMPILE -DIN_GCC   -g -O3     -I. -I. -I./config \
      -DGCC_INCLUDE_DIR=\"/home/rohanbk/ece668/lib/gcc-lib/sslittle-na-sstrix/2.7.2.3/include\" \
      -DGPLUSPLUS_INCLUDE_DIR=\"/home/rohanbk/ece668/include/g++\" \
      -DLOCAL_INCLUDE_DIR=\"/usr/local/include\" \
      -DCROSS_INCLUDE_DIR=\"/home/rohanbk/ece668/lib/gcc-lib/sslittle-na-sstrix/2.7.2.3/sys-include\" \
      -DTOOL_INCLUDE_DIR=\"/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/include\" \
      -c `echo ./cccp.c | sed 's,^\./,,'`
cccp.c: In function ‘macroexpand’:
cccp.c:8107: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
gcc -DCROSS_COMPILE -DIN_GCC   -g -O3   -o cccp cccp.o cexp.o \
      version.o obstack.o ` case "gcc" in "cc") echo "" ;; esac `  
rm -f cpp
ln cccp cpp > /dev/null 2>&1 \
     || cp cccp cpp
/bin/sh ./genmultilib "" \
      "" "" > multilib.h
gcc -DCROSS_COMPILE -DIN_GCC   -g -O3     -I. -I. -I./config \
  -DSTANDARD_STARTFILE_PREFIX=\"/home/rohanbk/ece668/lib/\" \
  -DSTANDARD_EXEC_PREFIX=\"/home/rohanbk/ece668/lib/gcc-lib/\" \
  -DDEFAULT_TARGET_VERSION=\"2.7.2.3\" \
  -DDEFAULT_TARGET_MACHINE=\"sslittle-na-sstrix\" \
  -DTOOLDIR_BASE_PREFIX=\"/home/rohanbk/ece668/\" \
   \
  -c `echo ./gcc.c | sed 's,^\./,,'`
gcc.c: In function ‘translate_options’:
gcc.c:880: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:916: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘index’
gcc.c:925: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘index’
gcc.c: In function ‘read_specs’:
gcc.c:1140: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bzero’
gcc.c: In function ‘set_spec’:
gcc.c:1215: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:1225: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c: In function ‘record_temp_file’:
gcc.c:1464: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:1465: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c: In function ‘choose_temp_base’:
gcc.c:1586: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:1589: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:1598: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c: In function ‘putenv’:
gcc.c:1623: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:1631: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c:1648: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c: In function ‘build_search_list’:
gcc.c:1669: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:1675: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:1689: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:1690: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:1702: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:1703: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:1713: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c: In function ‘find_a_file’:
gcc.c:1743: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:1756: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:1769: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:1770: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’
gcc.c:1782: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:1783: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’
gcc.c:1801: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:1802: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’
gcc.c:1813: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:1814: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’
gcc.c:1832: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:1833: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’
gcc.c:1843: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:1844: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’
gcc.c: In function ‘add_prefix’:
gcc.c:1891: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c: In function ‘pexecute’:
gcc.c:2098: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c: In function ‘execute’:
gcc.c:2172: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:2272: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c: In function ‘process_command’:
gcc.c:2357: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:2382: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:2389: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strncpy’
gcc.c:2391: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:2413: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:2420: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strncpy’
gcc.c:2422: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:2445: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:2452: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strncpy’
gcc.c:2454: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:2499: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c:2504: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c:2509: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c:2652: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strncpy’
gcc.c:2653: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’
gcc.c:2888: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c: In function ‘do_spec_1’:
gcc.c:3133: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:3167: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:3172: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:3173: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’
gcc.c:3211: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:3214: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:3233: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:3236: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:3258: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:3259: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strncpy’
gcc.c:3271: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:3315: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:3323: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:3323: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:3332: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:3366: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:3366: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:3383: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c:3402: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c:3524: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:3524: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:3554: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:3554: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:3727: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:3727: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:3794: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:3805: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c: In function ‘handle_braces’:
gcc.c:3850: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c:3869: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c:3879: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:3883: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c: In function ‘find_file’:
gcc.c:4123: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:4123: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:4124: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:4125: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’
gcc.c: In function ‘is_directory’:
gcc.c:4151: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:4153: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:4165: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c: In function ‘main’:
gcc.c:4214: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:4240: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:4241: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:4263: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c:4280: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
gcc.c:4282: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c:4283: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcat’
gcc.c:4382: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c:4388: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c:4395: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c:4401: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c:4410: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c:4422: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c:4432: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bzero’
gcc.c:4587: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c: In function ‘lookup_compiler’:
gcc.c:4625: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:4648: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c: In function ‘xmalloc’:
gcc.c:4664: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
gcc.c: In function ‘xrealloc’:
gcc.c:4675: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘realloc’
gcc.c: In function ‘concat’:
gcc.c:4687: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c:4691: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
gcc.c: In function ‘save_string’:
gcc.c:4726: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bcopy’
gcc.c: In function ‘fatal’:
gcc.c:4803: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
gcc.c: In function ‘used_arg’:
gcc.c:5007: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
gcc.c: In function ‘set_multilib_dir’:
gcc.c:5068: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c:5079: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c:5127: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strncpy’
gcc.c: In function ‘print_multilib_info’:
gcc.c:5168: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c:5192: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc.c:5233: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’
gcc -DCROSS_COMPILE -DIN_GCC   -g -O3   -o xgcc gcc.o version.o  obstack.o ` case "gcc" in "cc") echo "" ;; esac `  
gcc.o: In function `perror_with_name':
/home/rohanbk/ece668/gcc-2.7.2.3/gcc.c:4750: warning: `sys_nerr' is deprecated; use `strerror' or `strerror_r' instead
gcc.o: In function `choose_temp_base':
/home/rohanbk/ece668/gcc-2.7.2.3/gcc.c:1595: warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp' or `mkdtemp'
cp xgcc gcc-cross
./xgcc -B./ -dumpspecs > tmp-specs
mv tmp-specs specs
echo "__foo () {}" > dummy.c
./xgcc -B./ -DCROSS_COMPILE -DIN_GCC   -g -O3 -I./include -c dummy.c
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar rc libgcc1.null dummy.o
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x48)[0x40131da8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6[0x4012feb0]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6[0x4012f5a8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_default_xsputn+0xc8)[0x400a1bb8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_padn+0xed)[0x40094ded]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0x27bf)[0x40075fef]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__vsprintf_chk+0xa4)[0x4012f654]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__sprintf_chk+0x2d)[0x4012f59d]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x8061b42]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x804e836]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x8050f8a]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x805339f]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x804bc2b]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x804c36a]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe5)[0x4004a775]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x8049481]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08076000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 359681     /home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar
08076000-08077000 r-xp 0002d000 08:06 359681     /home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar
08077000-08078000 rwxp 0002e000 08:06 359681     /home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar
08da0000-08dc1000 rwxp 08da0000 00:00 0          [heap]
40000000-4001c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 275826     /lib/ld-2.9.so
4001c000-4001d000 r-xp 0001b000 08:06 275826     /lib/ld-2.9.so
4001d000-4001e000 rwxp 0001c000 08:06 275826     /lib/ld-2.9.so
4001e000-4001f000 r-xp 4001e000 00:00 0          [vdso]
4001f000-40021000 rwxp 4001f000 00:00 0 
40021000-40022000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 237234     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES
40022000-40029000 r-xs 00000000 08:06 220846     /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
40029000-4002c000 rwxp 40029000 00:00 0 
40034000-40190000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40190000-40191000 ---p 0015c000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40191000-40193000 r-xp 0015c000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40193000-40194000 rwxp 0015e000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40194000-40198000 rwxp 40194000 00:00 0 
401ab000-401b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 269345     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
401b8000-401b9000 r-xp 0000c000 08:06 269345     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
401b9000-401ba000 rwxp 0000d000 08:06 269345     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
bf9be000-bf9d3000 rw-p bffeb000 00:00 0          [stack]
make: *** [libgcc1.null] Aborted
make: *** Deleting file `libgcc1.null'

======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x48)[0x40131da8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6[0x4012feb0]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6[0x4012f5a8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_default_xsputn+0xc8)[0x400a1bb8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_padn+0xed)[0x40094ded]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0x27bf)[0x40075fef]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__vsprintf_chk+0xa4)[0x4012f654]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__sprintf_chk+0x2d)[0x4012f59d]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x8061b42]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x804e836]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x8050f8a]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x805339f]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x804bc2b]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x804c36a]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe5)[0x4004a775]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x8049481]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08076000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 359681     /home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar
08076000-08077000 r-xp 0002d000 08:06 359681     /home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar
08077000-08078000 rwxp 0002e000 08:06 359681     /home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar
08da0000-08dc1000 rwxp 08da0000 00:00 0          [heap]
40000000-4001c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 275826     /lib/ld-2.9.so
4001c000-4001d000 r-xp 0001b000 08:06 275826     /lib/ld-2.9.so
4001d000-4001e000 rwxp 0001c000 08:06 275826     /lib/ld-2.9.so
4001e000-4001f000 r-xp 4001e000 00:00 0          [vdso]
4001f000-40021000 rwxp 4001f000 00:00 0 
40021000-40022000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 237234     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES
40022000-40029000 r-xs 00000000 08:06 220846     /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
40029000-4002c000 rwxp 40029000 00:00 0 
40034000-40190000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40190000-40191000 ---p 0015c000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40191000-40193000 r-xp 0015c000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40193000-40194000 rwxp 0015e000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40194000-40198000 rwxp 40194000 00:00 0 
401ab000-401b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 269345     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
401b8000-401b9000 r-xp 0000c000 08:06 269345     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
401b9000-401ba000 rwxp 0000d000 08:06 269345     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
bf9be000-bf9d3000 rw-p bffeb000 00:00 0          [stack]
make: *** [libgcc1.null] Aborted
make: *** Deleting file `libgcc1.null'
```

This includes the backtrace and the resulting error message.

```
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x48)[0x40131da8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6[0x4012feb0]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6[0x4012f5a8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_default_xsputn+0xc8)[0x400a1bb8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_padn+0xed)[0x40094ded]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0x27bf)[0x40075fef]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__vsprintf_chk+0xa4)[0x4012f654]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__sprintf_chk+0x2d)[0x4012f59d]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x8061b42]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x804e836]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x8050f8a]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x805339f]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x804bc2b]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x804c36a]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe5)[0x4004a775]
/home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar[0x8049481]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08076000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 359681     /home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar
08076000-08077000 r-xp 0002d000 08:06 359681     /home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar
08077000-08078000 rwxp 0002e000 08:06 359681     /home/rohanbk/ece668/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin/ar
08da0000-08dc1000 rwxp 08da0000 00:00 0          [heap]
40000000-4001c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 275826     /lib/ld-2.9.so
4001c000-4001d000 r-xp 0001b000 08:06 275826     /lib/ld-2.9.so
4001d000-4001e000 rwxp 0001c000 08:06 275826     /lib/ld-2.9.so
4001e000-4001f000 r-xp 4001e000 00:00 0          [vdso]
4001f000-40021000 rwxp 4001f000 00:00 0 
40021000-40022000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 237234     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES
40022000-40029000 r-xs 00000000 08:06 220846     /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
40029000-4002c000 rwxp 40029000 00:00 0 
40034000-40190000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40190000-40191000 ---p 0015c000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40191000-40193000 r-xp 0015c000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40193000-40194000 rwxp 0015e000 08:06 74006      /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.9.so
40194000-40198000 rwxp 40194000 00:00 0 
401ab000-401b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 269345     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
401b8000-401b9000 r-xp 0000c000 08:06 269345     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
401b9000-401ba000 rwxp 0000d000 08:06 269345     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
bf9be000-bf9d3000 rw-p bffeb000 00:00 0          [stack]
make: *** [libgcc1.null] Aborted
make: *** Deleting file `libgcc1.null'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to install SimpleScalar

```
1) on Ubuntu (or whichever Linux you use) first do--

sudo apt-get update

2) Getting required applications

sudo apt-get install flex-old bison gedit

3) Start extraction

mkdir /tmp/simplescalar
cd /tmp/simplescalar/
wget http://csrl.unt.edu/downloads/simplescalar.tgz
tar xvfz simplescalar.tgz

4)
sudo apt-get install g++-3.4 gcc-3.4
//Alternatively, you can install gcc 3.4 using synaptic package manager
export CC="gcc-3.4";

5) setting up installation
export HOST=i686-unknown-linux 
export TARGET=sslittle-na-sstrix 
export IDIR=/opt/simplescalar

 6) Simplescalar tools
cd /tmp/simplescalar 
tar xvfz simpletools-2v0.tgz 
rm -rf gcc-2.6.3
sudo mkdir -p /opt/simplescalar
sudo mv f2c-1994.09.27/ glibc-1.09/ ssbig-na-sstrix/ sslittle-na-sstrix/ /opt/simplescalar/

7)Simplescalar utils 
cd /tmp/simplescalar 
tar xvfz simpleutils-990811.tar.gz
cd /tmp/simplescalar/simpleutils-990811  
./configure --host=$HOST --target=$TARGET --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --prefix=$IDIR 
make CC=gcc-3.4 
sudo make install CC=gcc-3.4



8)Simplescalar!!

cd /tmp/simplescalar 
tar xvfz simplesim-3v0d.tgz
cd simplesim-3.0 
make config-pisa
make CC=gcc-3.4


>>You will get "My work is done here" :)
cd /tmp/simplescalar 
sudo mv simplesim-3.0 
/opt/simplescalar
9) Now the hard part

cd /tmp/simplescalar/ 
tar xvfz gcc-2.7.2.3.ss.tar.gz
cd /tmp/simplescalar/gcc-2.7.2.3 
export PATH=$PATH:$IDIR/sslittle-na-sstrix/bin
./configure --host=$HOST --target=$TARGET --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --prefix=$IDIR  
make LANGUAGES="c c++" CFLAGS=-O3 CC=gcc-3.3
>>>>Error! Many errors about \ missing in insn-output.o
gedit insn-output.c

>>>> Edit file insn-output.c and add a \ (backslash) at the end of lines 675, 750, and 823.
make LANGUAGES="c c++" CFLAGS=-O3 CC=gcc-3.4
 >> Error! about libgcc2.a
gedit Makefile


 >>Edit file Makefile and add -I/usr/include to the end of line 130.


make LANGUAGES="c c++" CFLAGS=-O3 CC=gcc-3.4
sudo cp patched/sys/cdefs.h 
/opt/simplescalar/sslittle-na-sstrix/include/sys/

make enquire CC=gcc-3.4
/opt/simplescalar/simplesim-3.0/sim-safe 
./enquire -f > float.h-cross

sudo make install LANGUAGES="c c++" CFLAGS=-O3 CC=gcc-3.4 PATH=$PATH:/opt/simplescalar/bin




 10) Testing the installation!!!
cd /tmp/simplescalar 
/opt/simplescalar/bin/sslittle-na-sstrix-gcc hello.c
/opt/simplescalar/simplesim-3.0/sim-safe a.out
```

Comment: Can SimpleScalar run spec2006? Does it support write-through cache? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Build simpleutils with `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1`.  This fixes the `sprintf()` buffer overflow problem with ar.

The default for Ubuntu >= 8.10 is `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=`2, which breaks several old C programs.